# Trailing backslash issue with grok filters in logstash

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

Trailing backslash issue while using grok filters in Logstash

The messages should be parsed with "repo" value as "test" and "test-group" respectively, but the third message has a grok parse error because its missing a backslash and grok filter is failing to parse "resource_path" for it. I wanted to skip the api from parsing as a repo and that's the reason I had to implement a regex to do it.

I wanted to know if there's any workaround for it such that the messages that don't end with a trailing backslash still get parsed and don't throw errors.

```
Test messages used:



20190815175019|9599|REQUEST|14.56.55.120|anonymous|POST|/api/test/Lighter-test-group|HTTP/1.1|200|452

20190815175019|9599|REQUEST|14.56.55.120|anonymous|POST|/api/test-group/|HTTP/1.1|200|452

20190815175019|9599|REQUEST|14.56.55.120|anonymous|POST|/api/test-group|HTTP/1.1|200|452
```

Grok filter:

```
 filter {
    grok {
    break_on_match => false
    match => { "message" => "%{DATA:timestamp_local}\|%{NUMBER:duration}\|%{WORD:requesttype}\|%{IP:clientip}\|%{DATA:username}\|%{WORD:method}\|%{DATA:resource}\|%{DATA:protocol}\|%{NUMBER:statuscode}\|%{NUMBER:bytes}" }
      }
      grok {
        break_on_match => false
        match => { "resource" => "^(\/)+[^\/]+/%{DATA:repo}/%{GREEDYDATA:resource_path}" }
      }
        }
```

Expected result :

```
 {
        "@timestamp" => 2019-08-20T19:09:48.008Z,
                   "path" => "/Users/hack/test-status.log",
        "timestamp_local" => "20190815175019",
               "username" => "anonymous",
                 "method" => "POST",
                   "repo" => "test-group",
                  "bytes" => "452",
            "requesttype" => "REQUEST",
               "protocol" => "HTTP/1.1",
               "duration" => "9599",
               "clientip" => "14.56.55.120",
               "resource" => "/api/test-group/",
             "statuscode" => "200",
                "message" => "20190815175019|9599|REQUEST|14.56.55.120|anonymous|POST|/api/test-group/|HTTP/1.1|200|452",
                   "host" => "empty",
               "@version" => "1"
    }

    actual output:

    {
             "@timestamp" => 2019-08-20T19:09:48.009Z,
                   "path" => "/Users//hack/test-status.log",
        "timestamp_local" => "20190815175019",
               "username" => "anonymous",
                 "method" => "POST",
                  "bytes" => "452",
            "requesttype" => "REQUEST",
               "protocol" => "HTTP/1.1",
               "duration" => "9599",
               "clientip" => "14.56.55.120",
               "resource" => "/api/test-group",
             "statuscode" => "200",
                "message" => "20190815175019|9599|REQUEST|14.56.55.120|anonymous|POST|/api/test-group|HTTP/1.1|200|452",
                   "host" => "empty",
               "@version" => "1",
                   "tags" => [
            [0] "_grokparsefailure"
     ]
   }
```

Comment: I did not get you, all the logs example are working with the first grok!

Comment: You should have shortened your question to just the second grok filter.

Comment: I'm not sure it's the best solution, but you could make the second backslash optional, like this: `^(\/)+[^\/]+/%{DATA:repo}(/|)%{GREEDYDATA:resource_path}`

Comment: @baudsp my main intention is to skip the first two values of the message and parse the third value as "repo". For /api/test/Lighter-test-group/xyz , repo is getting parse as "Lighter-test-group" which is the right value but for /api/test/Lighter-test-group,/api/test i see grokparsefailures.  For message /api/test or /api/test/ ,the repo value needs to be empty string or just empty

Comment: I got it working using this   /[^/]+/[^/]+(/|)(?<repo>[^/]+)?(/%{GREEDYDATA:resource_path})?    ..Please let me know if this can be refactored